# mapping class group of a 4-punctured sphere

Tags: low-dimensional-topology, mapping-class-group

I am reading Farb and Margalit's *A primer on Mapping Class groups* which can be found in the following link: http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/farbmarg.pdf.

My question is regarding the relationship between the mapping class group of a $4$-punctured sphere and that of the torus, as described in section 2.2.5. On page 55 they discuss a construction of  a $(p,q)$-curve on the torus in order to obtain a similar construction for a $(p,q)$-curve on a $4$-punctured sphere:

"Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be two simple closed curves in $T^2$ that intersect each other in one point. We identify $\alpha$ with $(1, 0) \in Z^2$ and $\beta$ with $(0, 1) ∈ Z^2$. Let $(p, q)$
be a primitive element of $Z^2$. A simple closed curve $\gamma$ in $T^2$ is a $(p, q)$-
curve if we have $(i\hat (γ, β),i \hat(γ,α)) = ±(p, q)$. To construct the $(p, q)$-curve,
we start by taking $p$ parallel copies of $α$, and we modify this collection by a
$2π/q$ twist along $β$."

I cannot figure out what they mean by the last sentence . What does it mean to  twist the $\alpha$-curves along $\beta$? Can you possibly help me understand this by pictures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with you that this language is a bit confusing. I had a discussion about this with Dan Margalit when I read that book.

Here is a local picture in a neighborhood of $\beta$.

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

$------$

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

The horizontal arc is $\beta$ and the vertical arcs are the copies of $\alpha$.  If we cut $\alpha$ at each intersection point with $\beta$ and then connect the $i-th$ strands of $\alpha$ on the bottom to the $(i+1)-st$ strand of alpha at the top (cyclically), we will get a connected curve.  Try it on the torus for $p=2$ and $q=3$.

Comment: thanks, it was really helpful. I have another question, on the same page they say if you take two curves $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that intersect at one point on $T^2$, then under the hyperelliptic involution they descend to two closed curves $\bar{\alpha}$ and $\bar{\beta}$ on $S^2$. This is obviously incorrect for the standard meridian and longitude (${0} \times S^1$ and $S^1\times {0}$) on $T^2$, because (at least) one of them descends to an arc on $S^2$. So what they mean by this construction?

Comment: @braidrep I don't have the copy of my book right now. Please give me some times. Let me go back and read the book, After that I'll let you know. It might take a few days since I am away. But yes, what you said, makes sense. And I don't remember the exact proof. Otherwise you can directly email to Dan. He will help you.

Comment: The argument of the book is correct. Both the curves will give some non- trivial curves. Draw the picture, you can see it.

Comment: thanks. I will put the question separately on here in case anyone else could explain sooner.

Comment: @braidrep I think I already gave you the answer in my last comment. They indeed represent a curve in their images. You did some miscalculation. Draw the picture properly, you can see it. And if you think my last answer was helpful, you can accept the answer.

Comment: okay, I think I got it now. First we take the image of the curve under the involution and then take the quotient of both the curve and its image under the involution again, my mistake was that I took the quotient of only the curve.

Comment: @braid yes. Sometimes this kind of confusion happens.

Comment: Do you think you could clarify what "by $2\pi/q$ along $\beta$" means?

Comment: It seems to be a typo, where the angle should be "2\pi q/p".