# Dehn twist generators for mapping class group of a punctured disc

Tags: geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology, mapping-class-group

Can you help me find a reference or explain how to find explicit Dehn twist generators for $MCG(D_n,\partial D_n)$, mapping class group of a $n$-punctured disc? (for the problem I am working on, $n=3,4$ would be sufficient).

PS: I asked a related question here:[mapping class group of a 4-punctured sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2593969/mapping-class-group-of-a-4-punctured-sphere), which for $n=3$ discusses the relationship to the mapping class group of a torus. But I cannot find explicit Dehn twist generators based on that question at the moment (apparently Dehn twists about the curves $\alpha$ and $\beta$ there are two of the generators, but I do not know how that answer counts boundary Dehn twists as part of the generators).

Comment: I think for explicit relations you need to use branched cover. I don't remeber those arguments absolutely. But it's a way of doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the generators to be "half twists" exchanging two consecutive punctures.

You can make suggesting pictures by looking at the effect on the "equator", the horizontal line going through all the pictures.

Here is a picture I stole from [*Ordering Braids*](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/bertold.wiest/bouquin.pdf), by Dehornoy, Dynnikov, Rolfsen and Wiest (a great book!). It shows $\sigma_1$, the half-twist exchanging the first and second punctures.

[image]

You can also take a look at *Braid Groups*, by Kassel and Turaev, in particular section 1.6.